# Cesàro summation and operations

Tags: reference-request, divergent-series

We are reading now about Cesàro summation. And there is a remark that:

> We want $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ Cesàro-summable, then the Cauchy product 
>   $$(c_n)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}$$ 
>   is Cesàro-summable.
>   And that is not true, for example that does not hold for Grandi's series.

We are wondering that for elementary arithmetic operations ($+ -  ×  ÷ $),  did people ask the same question? We think if we have $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ Cesàro-summable then the sum $$(c_n)= (a_n + b_n)$$ should be Cesàro-summable, but we are not totally sure.

Could you please let us know if there is any book which wrote about that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book you are now reading should have already covered that Cesaro summation is linear:

Given Cesaro-summable sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ and any constants $A, B$, the sequence $(Aa_n + Bb_n)$ is also Cesaro-summable, and further,
$$\sum^C (Aa_n + Bb_n) = A\,\sum^C a_n + B\,\sum^C b_n$$
where I am using $\overset C\sum$ to denote Cesaro-summation.

Note that subtraction is covered in that formula by taking $A = 1, B = -1$.

In general it is not true that $(a_nb_n)$ or $\left(\frac {a_n}{b_n}\right)$ are Cesaro-summable just because $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are. And even when they are Cesaro-summable, there is no reason to expect them to converge to the product or ratio of $\overset C\sum a_n$ and $\overset C\sum b_n$. This is only to be expected, as the same is true for ordinary series summation.